# Python UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8c in position 2: invalid start byte

Tags: python, syntax, hex, decode

anyone know how do i decode my Hex value on Python version 3.6.0 ?

i was using x.decode("hex") but since python update it doesn't work anymore.

here is my hex value:

```html
01008C647620302E31302E372070762039393130333120736E20333137337C6661336232653863206D7A20313778313720736B6620343235357C34376330643162302073706620333237397C363236373361376520627066203332363137307C61653138366364642073746620323538397C623634383035633220616D66203335333230357C633736333133626200
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3.6 there is no need to decode strings (of type `str`), since they are already utf-8. Further, the normal `decode` function, allows only "standard" string decodings. That is, this function cannot decode hex.

Instead, this "special" decoding functionality is moved to `codecs.decode`. Thus, you want to rewrite your code as:

```
import codecs
x = "01008C647620302E31302E372070762039393130333120736E20333137337C6661336232653863206D7A20313778313720736B6620343235357C34376330643162302073706620333237397C363236373361376520627066203332363137307C61653138366364642073746620323538397C623634383035633220616D66203335333230357C633736333133626200"
codecs.decode(x, 'hex')
```